# Unable to Merge Small ORC Files using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop2, orc

I have an external ORC table with a large number of the small files, which are coming from the source on daily basis. I need to merge these files into larger files.

I tried to load ORC files to the spark and save with overwrite method

```
val fileName = "/user/db/table_data/"  //This table contains multiple partition on date column with small data files.
val df = hiveContext.read.format("orc").load(fileName)
df.repartition(1).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("date").orc("/user/db/table_data/)
```

But `mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)` is deleting all the data from the HDFS. When I tried without `mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)` method, it was throwing error file already exists.

Can anyone help me to proceed?

Comment: You need to save them to another directory. And after job is completed you can replace old directory with a new one.

Comment: I can try this to resolve my problem. But what is the use of write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite), if we need to move the file after completion of job.

Comment: SaveMode.Overwrite says Spark to clear target directory before running the job if it exists. In your case your source and target directory are the same.
SaveMode.Overwrite is useful when you need to run a job multiple times and you don't want to clear results from previous run.

Comment: Thanks @Avseiytsev. I am clear now why SaveMode.Overwrite is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Avseiytsev, I have stored by merged orc files in different folder as source in HDFS and moved the data to the table path after the completion of the job.